# Firing a function with onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, html

I made a cookie clicker using javascript and html, and at the moment I have it made so that upon clicking an image, it fires a function which increases your score. I want to make it so that instead of only being able to click the image, you can just click any button on the keyboard to fire the same function. I've only seen code to do this in an input field. I'm not sure if "document.addEventListener("keydown", function())" is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: No it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    console.log('my code');
};
```

Edit (or):

```
document.onkeydown = myFn;
```

Comment: The second one works perfectly! Thank you that's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To listen for keypress you can add keydown event on document

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", callBack, false);

function callBack(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  console.log(keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a event handler to your event.

If you want to assign for the whole document, use this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
```

```js
document.getElementById("yourinput").addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

```html
<input id="yourinput" type="text" />
```

Comment: Well, I don't want an input field I just want the whole document to be listening for a keydown event

Comment: Updated the answer, instead of adding it to the input, add it to only document.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
   console.log('a');
});
```

should work.

However, some browsers don't give document focus, which is required for keydown events.

The classic approach to this (which works more universally) is to create an off-screen `<input>` element, and give it a `blur` event to regain focus when it loses it. This will force focus to always stay on that input, then it can receive key events.

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.style.position = 'absolute';
input.style.left = '-100000px';
input.addEventListener('blur', () => input.focus());
input.addEventListener('keydown', () => console.log('key down'));
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.focus();
```

This code:
 - creates a new input element
 - positions it absolutely way off the left of the screen (so it's not visible)
 - adds a blur event which automatically gets focus back
 - adds the keydown event itself